# 3d object to 2d template

Tags: 2d, template

I have a 3d model of a chair in a .dae format

I want to convert it in its real dimensions and print its surfaces in paper so I can use it as templates.

Since its my first time using blender, I was wondering if something like that is possible, and if it easy how easy it will be to do it?

Are there any resources that you recommend? (Its kinda difficult to make any research on it because I dont know the right terminology)

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is an unwrap? In that case you need to select the edges that you want to cut and press U > Mark Seam. Then select all and press U > Unwrap. Check the UV Editor window and UV > Export UV Layout to save it as a PNG